# Polynomial long division with complex numbers

Tags: automation, polynom, polynomials

I heard of the `polynom` LaTeX package, which can be used to do polynomial long division in LaTeX documents; I have even used it myself before for normal polynomials with real coefficients.

However, now I have to divide polynomials with complex coefficients (something like `(x^2+1)/(x+i)`) and that doesn't seem to be possible with the `polynom` package.

Is there some way to achieve this in LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to tex,sx.

Comment: Anything is possible.  Is it worth the effort?

Comment: If you look for a solver, programs like Mathematica etc. provide that. If you want to typeset a solution from any of those programs, Latex can help you. Having both in one place ... isn't the best approach in my view. Honestly, have a look into the polynom-packages code, and you easily see, why ...